# PHP doesn't like echo "<div>";

Tags: php

What's wroing with this?

```
<div id="container">

        <div id="container_middle">

            <?php

                echo "<div>";

                    echo 'simple';

                echo "</div>";

            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Notice the marker:

[image]

If I replace the div with e.g a paragraph, it works fine:

[image]

It works fine with eveything except for a div.

Comment: You're asking about your text editor, not PHP.  You have not told us what editor it is.

Comment: What "marker" ? This is a problem with your editor.

Comment: What is the output when you put the <div>'s outside the php declaration tags?

Comment: Your editor is confused (which is sad, because this is not an uncommon case). Just execute your code to realize, that PHP accepts it.

Comment: I am using Notepad++. I didn't know that mattered. @Chris when I do that, it's fine.

Comment: @erdomester: It matters, because other text editors don't have that problem.  [Geany](http://geany.org), for example, likes this just fine.

Comment: It has something to do with the your PHP syntax analysis within the editor, try another editor maybe? I recommend Sublime text 2?

Comment: @erdomester: If you're asking why your text editor highlights something, how could it not matter which editor?

Comment: I didn't think Notepad++ could have problem with so simple things. @Chris I downloaded it but it doesn't highlight the closing part of a block if I click the opening part. Is there way to enable this option?

Comment: yeah, you can download a bracket extension package, brilliant! [here](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter)

Comment: Well guys thank you for your help. I ran the code of course but I always check it even though it's working fine. I couldn't find anything about this irregularity so I needed to turn to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can handle this fine, it is your editor that doesn't like PHP echoing a `<div>`.

However, it is a better practise to avoid echoing HTML in PHP, instead do something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="container_middle">
        <div><?php echo 'simple' ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's really hard to do when I need to echo a table :)

Comment: @erdomester No, it isn't.

Comment: Haha, you are right :) I just used simple html with the divs and now the problem is solved.